# Synchronization in Multiplayer in Unity3D

Tags: network-programming, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a Unity Network game in which I have two players which have some basic moves. One player is controlled by the server and the other player is controlled by the client.

To accomplish this I have made a client/server connection. After the connection is made, I can see both players on both sides of the screen. I have used the RPC method.

Now if I make a move on the server, I can see the server player move on the client side as well. This means they are synchronized. But when I make a move on the client side, only the client player makes a move. I cannot see that move on the server side. Why doesn't this work?

I have written the code in UnityScript.

```
#pragma strict
var farword:boolean=false;
var backword:boolean=false;

var FirstPlayer:GameObject;
var SecondPlayer:GameObject;

var isFarword=false;
var isBackword=false;
function Update () {

    if(isFarword)
    { 
        networkView.RPC("ChangePos",RPCMode.All);
        isFarword=false;
    }
}

@RPC
function ChangePos()
{
    if(isFarword)
    {
        if(Network.isServer)
        {
            FirstPlayer.transform.Translate(0,0,1);
            isFarword=false;
        }
        if(Network.isClient)
        {
            SecondPlayer.transform.Translate(0,0,1);
            isFarword=false;
        }
    }
    else if(isBackword)
    {
        if(Network.isServer)
        {
            FirstPlayer.transform.Translate(0,0,-1);
            isBackword=false;
        }
        if(Network.isClient)
        {
            SecondPlayer.transform.Translate(0,0,-1);
            isBackword=false;
        }
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.RepeatButton(new Rect(1000,100,80,70),"Farword"))
    {
        isFarword=true;
    }
    if(GUI.RepeatButton(new Rect(850,100,80,70),"second"))
    {
        isBackword=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code is the part where it goes wrong.

Comment: Where do you create the characters? do you use instantiate ? or just drag/drop in the editor. if instantiate use networkinstantiate instead of normal instantiate . sample usage ( its in c# but not hard to translate) http://pastebin.com/3kVAygHs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably where you instantiate the players..

Use the network events to create the players, eg..

**Network.OnPlayerConnected**, is where you should Network.Instantiate the client's player, and **Network.OnServerInitialized** is where you should Network.Instantiate the server's player. This will result in each of them being the owner.

Also, network games have some psycho logic to think through, try to always rather use NetworkView.isMine to determine who is the owner of the object and who isn't. Remember, only the owner is supposed to be able to move the object, the other players are listening in for coordinates.

Goodluck!